# Cypress Allure reports are not getting generated

Tags: cypress

I am integrating cypress allure reports in my APIs automation but the reports are being displayed as loading.

My `cypress.config.js` files looks like this

```
/// <reference types="@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin" />

const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

const allureWriter = require('@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/writer');
// import allureWriter from "@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/writer";

module.exports = defineConfig({
    e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
            allureWriter(on, config);
            return config;
        }
    }
});
```

My support/e2e.js file looks this

```
`// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
/// <reference types="@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin" />

import './commands'
import '@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin';
require('@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin');`
```

and my package.jos looks like this

```
{
  "name": "autocy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "cypress:run": "npx cypress run --browser chrome --headless --spec cypress/e2e/Accounts/*.js",
    "allure:report": "allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report && allure open allure-report",
    "beforetest": "npm run clean:folders",
    "test": "npm run cypress:run && npm run report:allure",
    "aftertest": "npm run allure:report",
    "allure:clear_results": "(if exist allure-results (rmdir /S /Q allure-results && mkdir allure-results))"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress": "^13.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin": "^2.40.0",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.24.0",
    "mocha-allure-reporter": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

i have trying every possible way but my reports are blank data is not being generated

I also trying to downgrade my java to 8 but still the reports are null

Comment: You have two `module.exports = ` in cypress config, that's got to be causing some trouble. How did that happen?

Comment: i was just trying to explore, even single module.exports didnt work out

Comment: It makes the question misleading. If you have explorations in your code, you should point them out.

Comment: i have edited the file code

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with shelex plugin - it doesn’t support cypress 13 yet.

This is link to discussion https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/27113

Comment: Oh, I see you’ve already participated in that discussion

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved with the release of the official Allure Cypress integration:

- NPM Package: [allure-cypress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/allure-cypress)
- Documentation: [Allure Integration with Cypress](https://allurereport.org/docs/cypress/)

Please update to this latest version to address the issue.